# Counting from 0 to N

Tags: c++, loops

I have counter which counter upto a digit. but it is not starting from 0.
It is starting from 1.

```
for(int i = 0; i <31; i++ )
{
     my_count.incrementCounter();
     my_count.printCounter();
}
```

In incrementCounter

```
if (currCountVal < maxCountVal - 1)
{
    currCountVal++;
    overFlow = false;
}
else
{
    overFlow = true;
    currCountVal = 0;
}
```

In printCounter

```
{
    cout << currCountVal << endl;
}
```

I expect the output should start from 0 but it is starting from 1.

Comment: What do you set `currCountVal` to in `my_count`'s constructor?

Comment: Starts off with 0. Literally increments it. Prints it. Wonders why it's 1?

Comment: I set currCountVal  0

Comment: Yes, then you called `incrementCounter()`.

Comment: You increment and then print the value.  If you started with zero, the value would be one when you first print it.  You can resolve this by A) switching the order you increment and print, or B) starting from -1.  B is pretty hacky, I suggest using A.

Comment: btw, while your variable and function names are perfectly acceptable, your indentation style is all over the place.  This might be the result of moving your code to StackOverflow, or might be present in the original.  Hard to tell.

Answer (score 7):

In your `for` loop:

```
 my_count.incrementCounter();
 my_count.printCounter();
```

you increment **before** you print, so of course it's going to be 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you increment it **before** you print it. `currCountVal` presumably starts at `0`, then you increment it to `1`, and then you print it for the first time. Swapping the `my_count.incrementCounter();` and the `my_count.printCounter();` should solve the issue based on the code you've shown (although it would have been good to have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).